# How do you update a checkbox in a marketing cloud microsite with a salesforce contact value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am attempting to create a custom preference centre, where our subscribers (salesforce contacts) can choose which communications they would like to receive.

I'm very new to ampscript, can anyone advise how to update a checkbox field with a salesforce value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the **RetrieveSalesforceObjects()** and **UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()** AMPScript functions to retrieve and set the preferences on the Contact record.

reference:  [AMPScript Functions for use with Salesforce.com](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/)

Updating the checkbox is a matter of using AMPScript logic to manipulate the HTML of the checkbox input tag.  If the preferences is true, then the input tag should have the checked attribute set.  If the preferences is false, then the checked attribute should not be set.

example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="preference1" value="true" checked> attribute checked
 <input type="checkbox" name="preference2" value="true"> attribute not checked
```

Comment: Thanks David - My salesforce information is now displaying correctly.

Comment: Hi David my microsite is displaying all the preferences chosen in salesforce although - with the following Ampscript     
<input type="checkbox" name="m"  id="email_m" %%[If @mnews== "true" Then ]%% checked="true"  %%[EndIf]%%>

Would my UpdateSingleSalesforce line be on the same microsite or should it be within the confirmation microsite when the “Update” button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but here's some sample of the many ways you might implement AMPScript and SSJS to leverage CRM data with some checkboxes https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfv22p3s8h223m7/PrefCtr.html?dl=0&raw=1

Comment: appreciate the comment and sample but SSJS is harder to understand then ampscript.

Comment: I appreciate you contributing this code via Dropbox, but it'd be more helpful if you lifted out the pertinent parts and included them in your answer.

Comment: @CherylM you'll find that SSJS is way more mainstream than AMPScript and it's certainly better for coding in landing pages.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - I've been reading a lot of your comments Adam, for myself I find the learning curve for SSJS is greater then Ampscript. If I had your knowledge of SSJS and MC  I would definitely apply it in creating our Custom Preference Center.  I appreciate any assistance you can provide in future.